# How to adjust CSS to display correctly in IE 6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have the following HTML+CSS that may be displayed on some small number of older Windows XP machines with IE 6 as a web browser. On a newer browser it should look like this:

[image]

but IE 6 makes it look like this:

[image]

So I was curious if there's anything I can do to try to fix this for IE 6?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcgLkdc9/2/) to show the code.

The image used was this:
[image]

html:

```
<span id="lbl01">User Commands:</span>
<div class="divSmBtns">
<a href="#" id="idBtn" draggable="false" class="smtbBtnCopy smtbBtn" title="whatever"></a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.divSmBtns{
    margin: -10px 10px 0px 8px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
}
.smtbBtnCopy{
    background-image: url(copy.gif);
}
.smtbBtn{
    width: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-size: 6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
.smtbBtn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.smtbBtn:active{
    background-size: 5px;
}
```

Comment: IE 6 ?? why back to stone age ??  :P

Comment: @YoYo: I know. I can't argue with a customer... they still have a small number of very ancient machines. I just wanted to try to fix it... and if not, I can say, "sorry, not compatible." I should add that this code should mostly run on their local "intranet"

Comment: Two problems. (1) `display: inline-table` is not supported in IE6. Use `display: inline`; (2) `background-size` is not supported in IE6. Use an `img` instead or increase the size of `a`.

Comment: Sir you can atleast suggest them to switch to basic firefox browser or some better,,, It will be big relief for you too for  future codes. I can understnd painful is it for coders to work on IE8 and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to support IE6, you will need to make some compromises with your mark-up and keep it simple.

As I said in the comments, two problems.

1. `display: inline-table` is not supported in IE6. Use `display: inline;`
2. `background-size` is not supported in IE6. Use an `img` instead of a background image.

A very simple solution would be to remove the `div` wrapping your `a`, and instead use the `a` to wrap an `img`. Something like this:

```
<span id="...">User Commands:</span>
<a href="#" id="..." class="smtbBtn " title="...">
    <img src='...' alt='...' />
</a>
```

And then, use that image for your hover interactions:

```
.smtbBtn { vertical-align: middle; }
.smtbBtn img { height: 14px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
.smtbBtn:hover img, .smtbBtn:active img { 
    border: 1px solid #f00; 
}
```

That will work well across all browser including the modern ones as well as IE going back to IE5.

**Demo Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mcgLkdc9/6/embedded/result/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.smtbBtn { vertical-align: middle; }
.smtbBtn img { height: 14px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
.smtbBtn:hover img, .smtbBtn:active img { 
    border: 1px solid #f00; 
}
```

```html
<span id="lbl01">User Commands:</span>
<a href="#" id="idBtn" draggable="false" class="smtbBtnCopy smtbBtn" title="Copy">
    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cALN.gif' alt='' />
</a>
```

---

#### Edit:

As was pointed out that IE6 will not support `transparent` for `border-color`, you will have to resort to either hacks or conditional comments (*as suggested in the other answer*).

1. ***Hack***: You could prefix a property by `_` (underscore) which will be recognized only by IE6 and ignored by other browsers. Similarly prefixing with an `*` (asterisk) will be recognized only by IE7.

*CSS:*

```
.smtbBtn img { height: 14px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
.smtbBtn img { _border-color: pink; _filter: chroma(color=pink); }
```

*Fiddle 2: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mcgLkdc9/8/embedded/result/*

2. ***Conditional comments***: You could use conditional comments to inject HTML i.e. in your case an `img` tag with a specific class for those styles. Remember that conditional comments are used for HTML not CSS.

*Markup:*

```
<a href="#" id="idBtn" draggable="false" class="smtbBtnCopy smtbBtn" title="Copy">
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cALN.gif' class='ie6img' alt='' />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 7]>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cALN.gif' alt='' />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cALN.gif' alt='' />
    <!--<![endif]-->
</a>
```

*CSS:*

```
.smtbBtn img { height: 14px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
.ie6img {
    border-color: pink; filter: chroma(color=pink);
}
```

*Fiddle 3: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a9f80cqf/4/embedded/result/*

**Note:** I have not tested the above two methods in IE6. I am using developer tools emulation in IE11. Which means, you will have to tweak that based on your experience.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation. One thing though, I don't think `transparent` property is supported for the `border` attribute. Is there something else I can use instead?

Comment: Oh yes @c00000fd, I missed that one out completely (*IE6 mode via dev tools works though!*). For the transparent border you could use this trick - http://martinivanov.net/2008/08/24/emulating-border-color-transparent-in-internet-explorer-6/

Comment: You know, if I simply add `border-color: pink; filter: chroma(color=pink);` it works with IE6 but then it starts showing pink border in the latest version of IE. Is there a way to add IE6 specific CSS without writing a whole new CSS file like was suggested by @GoosvandenBekerom?

Comment: @c00000fd: There, I have updated the answer to add your IE6 specific case. You will have to take it up from here, because I do not have IE6 and am only relying on emulation of IE11.

Comment: Appreciate your help! It works now. I went with the underscore hack. I didn't even know it existed, and since IE6 will never be updated/changed, we may assume that the underscore "trick" is a feature now.